# Html.TextBoxFor works but EditorFor throws an error - why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have the following code in my view:

```
@model MyDomain.ViewModels.EditCapacityViewModel
```

`   ....

```
@Html.EditorFor<Capacity, >(m => m.Capacity.NumberOfWeeks)
```

This is my ViewModel - straight pass through to my model class

```
public class EditCapacityViewModel
    {
        public Capacity Capacity { get; set; }
    }
```

My Capacity model class:

```
[Display(Name="Number of Weeks")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public virtual int NumberOfWeeks { get; set; }
```

Using the above code, I get the error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

If I convert the EditorFor to a TextBoxFor, it works.

I have no idea why this isn't working.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EditorFor` works only for strings without a custom template.

You'll need to create an `Int32` template on path `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Int32.cshtml` in order to make that work.

If you don't want to create a template for `Int32` type, use `TextBoxFor` that will work as you already realized.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in the original question.

Yes, I do have the code as you have highlighted, and am still getting the error.  The DataType was some testing.  I do want it to be an int.

Comment: @Urkel: why `NumberOfWeeks` is type date? It make no sense to me. Could you please explain what you tried to do?

Comment: No, NumberOfWeeks is type int.

Comment: But you have `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`

Comment: Ignore that, please.  I get the same error after deleting the DataType attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed the EditorFor helper was intelligent enough to convert an int to a string without a custom template - as the TextBoxFor does.